# MySQL drop table named `data`

Tags: mysql

So I have a MySQL database which contains a table named "data" which throws errors when attempting to import it into another MySQL database on a different server.

The data table is not important and I'd preferably like to delete it, but when using

```
DROP TABLE `data`;
```

in the database, it says "Unknown table 'dbname.data'"

The table exists, when using SHOW TABLES, I get

```
+------------------+
| Tables_in_dbname |
+------------------+
| data             |
| ...              |
+------------------+
```

(where ... represents the other table names)

Is there anyway to export all tables besides the data table, or is there anyway to drop the data table?

Thank you

Comment: What tool are you currently using for exporting tables? With `mysqldump` you can specify which tables you want to dump using `--tables` option: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tables

Comment: @MichalGasek this is exactly what I needed, thank you

Comment: show table name in hex: `SELECT hex(table_name) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'dbname' and table_name like 'data%';`